# Creating Horizontal Bars with Itertools and For Loops (Python)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, matplotlib, python-itertools

I've been playing around with Matplotlib and created a horizontal bar using the following algorithm (Full code and junk data provided at the bottom of this post).

```
# Version 1
ax.broken_barh([(depth_start[0], thick[0]), (depth_start[1], thick[1]), (depth_start[2], thick[2])], (25, 0.8),
               facecolors=('tab:brown', 'tab:blue', 'tab:green'))
```

which produces the following graphical output:

[image]

So I've been trying to make the code more efficient by introducing `itertools`

I managed to simplify the above code into a version 2:

```
# Version 2
for i in thick:
    ax.broken_barh([(next(cycle_depth), next(cycle_thick))], (15, 0.8), facecolors=(next(cycle_colour)))
```

Great, this also produces the above bar in the same order with the same colours.

**The Problem**

But I'm struggling with my next objective which is to replace `facecolors=('tab:brown', 'tab:blue', 'tab:green')` with a `function` that uses a `for loop`. This function ideally selects the correct colour for each bar based on the thickness. All 3 bars return a brown colour as the function continuously returns the value associated with the `else` statement (see image below).

I've attempted substituting `next(cycle_thick)` in place of the variable cycle_think in the function, but then only one of the colours is correct again.

The colour_checker() function is as follows:

```
def colour_checker():
    if cycle_thick == 10:
        return 'tab:green'
    elif cycle_thick == 20:
        return 'tab:blue'
    else:
        return 'tab:brown'

# Version 3
for i in thick:
    ax.broken_barh([(next(cycle_depth), next(cycle_thick))], (10, 0.8), facecolors=colour_checker())
```

Any hints or suggestions welcomed!

[image]

Full Code and Junk Data

```
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Junk data in the form of lists
depth_start = [90, 70, 40]  # top of lithology
thick = [30, 20, 10]  # thickness for each lithology
colour = ('tab:brown', 'tab:blue', 'tab:green')

# Lists to be cycled through
cycle_colour = itertools.cycle(colour)
cycle_depth = itertools.cycle(depth_start)
cycle_thick = itertools.cycle(thick)

#setting up the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def colour_checker():
    if cycle_thick == [0]:
        return 'tab:green'
    elif cycle_thick == [1]:
        return 'tab:blue'
    else:
        return 'tab:brown'


# Version 1
ax.broken_barh([(depth_start[0], thick[0]), (depth_start[1], thick[1]), (depth_start[2], thick[2])], (25, 0.8),
               facecolors=('tab:brown', 'tab:blue', 'tab:green'))

# Version 2
for i in thick:
    ax.broken_barh([(next(cycle_depth), next(cycle_thick))], (15, 0.8), facecolors=(next(cycle_colour)))

# Version 3
for i in thick:
    ax.broken_barh([(next(cycle_depth), next(cycle_thick))], (10, 0.8), facecolors=colour_checker())

ax.set_ylabel('X_UTM Position')
ax.set_xlabel('MAMSL')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you insist on using the cycler? The task is also not fully clear. Do you want to combine each indexed element from the three lists in a barh graph? Do you want to cycle through the three colors whatever the other two lists generate as bars? Do you want to a specific color if the barh graph has a specific length (e.g., 10 is green)? All three interpretations of your question are possible and are tackled differently.

Comment: Hi Mr. T

Thanks for the feedback and taking the time to work through my muddled question. I'll have to work on my making my questions clear moving forwards.

Yes, I was aiming to assign a particular colour to a particular length of barh.

My use of cycle wasn't necessary. Quite like the way that you used zip() func. Will be using more of that.

Comment: Phew. I was afraid you actually wanted a fourth, different version. Glad this is solved. zip is really an amazing tool to get rid of awkward indexing tasks. Have fun exploring matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the intention of the outcome was ambiguous, I have created examples for all three versions I can imagine.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Junk data in the form of lists
depth_start = [90, 70, 40, 200, 170, 140]  # top of lithology
thick = [30, 20, 10, 20, 10, 30]  # thickness for each lithology
colour = ('tab:brown', 'tab:blue', 'tab:green')

#setting up the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

#Version 1: using zip to chain all three lists
for start, length, color in zip(depth_start, thick, colour+colour[::-1]):
    ax.broken_barh([(start, length)], (-0.4, 0.8), facecolors=color)
    
#Version 2: color cycler repetitive color assignments 
from itertools import cycle
cycle_colour = cycle(colour)

for start, length in zip(depth_start, thick):
    ax.broken_barh([(start, length)], (0.6, 0.8), facecolors=next(cycle_colour))
    
#Version 3: lookup table to color bars of a specific length with a certain color
color_dic = {30: 'tab:brown', 20: 'tab:blue', 10: 'tab:green'}

for start, length in zip(depth_start, thick):
    ax.broken_barh([(start, length)], (1.6, 0.8), facecolors=color_dic[length])

ax.set_yticks(range(3)) 
ax.set_yticklabels(["Version 1", "Version 2", "Version 3"])   

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]